# Присвоить элементам массива значения не за один раз, а по отдельности

Tags: php, pdo, modx

Прошу помочь. Чтот запнулся с пониманием массивов.
Есть запрос:

```
$q = $modx->newQuery('modContext');
$where = array(
   'modContext.key:in' => array('web', 'mgr'),
   'cs.value:!=' => NULL,
   'cs.value:!=' => '',
);
$q->select(array(
   'modContext.key',
   'cs.key as setting_key',
   'cs.value'
));
$q->innerJoin('modContextSetting', 'cs', 'cs.context_key = modContext.key');
$q->where($where);
```

здесь where присваивается за один раз. Как бы разбить это действие на несколько. Типа:

```
$where['modContext.key:in'] => 'web';
$where['modContext.key:in'] => 'mgr';
$where['cs.value:!='] => NULL;
$where['cs.value:!='] => '';
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообще, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы where собирался по ходу кода, а потом использовался в двух разных запросах. Для этого нужно, чтобы в where элементы добавлялись вместе с условиями "like", "in" и т.п. У меня получалось только, что они перекрывали друг друга, где в итоге только последний элемент в массиве оставался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$where = []; //инициализация пустого массива, чтобы можно было присваивать значения через индексаторы
//... do something ...
$where['modContext.key:in'] = ['web', 'mgr'];
//... do something ...
$where['cs.value:!='] = null;
//... do something ...
$where['cs.value:!='] = ''; //обратите внимание, эта строчка перезапишет предыдущую, т.е. у Вас в массиве останется два значения, а не три

//Дальше как и у Вас:
$q->select(array(
   'modContext.key',
   'cs.key as setting_key',
   'cs.value'
));
$q->innerJoin('modContextSetting', 'cs', 'cs.context_key = modContext.key');
$q->where($where);
```

Comment: Вот я лопух... Вместо "=" писал "=>". Спасибо большое, добрый человек)

Comment: Не за что. Подобной ошибки можно избежать используя редактор кода с подсветкой синтаксиса. Редактор подскажет Вам, если допустите синтаксическую ошибку.